# What does "build against" mean?

Tags: build

What does the phrase "build (some program) against (some library)" mean? I read this many times, but can't figure what does it mean. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can read that as "build the program so that it will use/include this library"

Comment: Was also confused about this. It's very strange vocabulary. i would've called it "build using" or "build with"

Answer (score -2):

I will address this issue in terms of **Object Oriented Programming** (OOP) since it is the easiest and most widely use these days.

So if I am writing a program that creates and add some text in a txt file, I have different **existing** libraries to use.

These libraries enable me to utilise **predefined functions** which **feed** on my **own** information, to serve the purpose of the program I am building.

A Java example: `java.io.File` and `java.nio.file.Files`. The usage can depend sometimes on slight usage differences or simply preference.